# Minimum requered permision to execute MySql stored procedures from C# app

Tags: c#, mysql, privileges

I have a schema in MySQL '_users' which includes 1 table with two columns (username, telephone number). For simplicity lets assume that i have 4 store procedures.

- `SP_Find user`: Return the user telephone number (Select)
- `SP_Add user`: Add a new user and telephone number (Insert)
- `SP_Delete user`: Remove user (Delete) - delete row
- `SP_Update user`: Change the users telephone (Update)

I have one user in MySQL. In order for the C# connection to work i need to give to the user: 1) under the Administration Tab - Global Privileges - SELECT and 2) under the Schema Privileges - EXECUTE in '_users'.

When i try to remove the first one, the C# request to run any procedure is denied. I don't want to give 'Global Privileges - SELECT' to the c# app because ti will have access to Select through all schemas.

I would like to give access to my C# app only to run the stored procedures. How can i do this?

Comment: What if you execute the procedure in MySQL command line client? Does it need SELECT privilege?

Comment: You can fine tune permissions up to the level of individual procedures, see [grant](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html). You have to grant those permissions on the server (e.g. by the script that creates the database and the user). I am not sure which admin tab you are talking about though or if it does that (e.g. if it's a config window in your programming environment). Also check if your procedure is defined as `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` (instead of `definer`), as it would require the user to not only have permission to execute it, but also to all objects that the procedure uses.